# dataframe:drop object type colums with certain kinds of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to drop columns with more than 50 kinds of values using function?

here drop columns:date_dispatch,con_birth_dt,dat_cust_open,cust_mgr_team,mng_issu_date,created_date

```
app_train.select_dtypes('object').apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis = 0)

label                           1
date_dispatch                2883
con_birth_dt                12617
con_sex_mf                      2
dat_cust_open                 264
cust_mgr_team                2250
mng_issu_date                1796
um_num                         38
created_date                 2900
hqck_flag                       2
dqck_flag                       2
tzck_flag                       2
yhlcck_flag                     2
bzjck_flag                      2
gzck_flag                       2
jjsz_flag                       2
e_yhlcck_flag                   2
zq_flag                         2
xtsz_flag                       1
whsz_flag                       1
hjsz_flag                       2
yb_flag                         2
qslc_flag                       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) with `index` values filtered by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
a = app_train.select_dtypes('object').apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis = 0)
df = app_train.drop(a.index[a > 50], axis=1)
```

Another solution is add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for missing `columns` and then filter by `inverted` condition `<=`:

```
a = (app_train.select_dtypes('object')
              .apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis = 0)
              .reindex(app_train.columns, fill_value=0))

df = app_train.loc[:, a <= 50]
```

**Sample**:

```
app_train = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (app_train)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

a = (app_train.select_dtypes('object')
              .apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis = 0)
              .reindex(app_train.columns, fill_value=0))

df = app_train.loc[:, a <= 5]
print (df)
   B  C  D  E  F
0  4  7  1  5  a
1  5  8  3  3  a
2  4  9  5  6  a
3  5  4  7  9  b
4  5  2  1  2  b
5  4  3  0  4  b
```

Comment: another llittle question.how to drop column with over 50 kinds of value and with only one value simultaneously?

Comment: @LeeKing - You can use `df = app_train.drop(a.index[(a > 50) | (a == 1)], axis=1)` with second solution or `df = app_train.loc[:, (a <= 50) & (a != 1)]`

Answer (score 0):

#### [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) + [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

You can use `nunique` followed by `loc` with Boolean indexing:

```
n = 5  # maximum number of unique values permitted
counts = app_train.select_dtypes(['object']).apply(pd.Series.nunique)
df = app_train.loc[:, ~app_train.columns.isin(counts[counts > n].index)]

# data from jezrael
print(df)

   B  C  D  E  F
0  4  7  1  5  a
1  5  8  3  3  a
2  4  9  5  6  a
3  5  4  7  9  b
4  5  2  1  2  b
5  4  3  0  4  b
```